# How can i parse json file in spark? And how can i insert to dynamo DB in spark or hdfs?

Tags: json, scala, parsing, apache-spark

I want to parse json file in spark(scala).
Next i want to save the txt file..
Json file saved in HDFS.

How can i parse json file by using scala?

json file example)
metadata.json

```
{"ID": "ABCDEFG", "product": "computer", "review": "good"}
{"ID": "ZXCVBND", "product": "computer", "review": "bad"}
```

I want to parse ID and review.
after parse ==>

```
 ABCDEFG :: good
 ZXCVBND :: bad
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks pretty easy - read data from json, create query with Spark sql, and save data to hdfs:

```
val df = spark.read.json("json/in/hdfs/data.json")
df.show()
val myDF = spark.read.json(path)
myDF.printSchema()//for debug purposes
myDF.createOrReplaceTempView("myData")
val selectedDF = spark.sql("SELECT id, parse FROM myData")
                      .map(attributes => attributes(0) + " :: " + attributes(1)) 
selectedDF.write().fomat("json").saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...")
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading JSON in Spark is a matter of using the SparkSession `.read.json(path)` which will return a DataFrame (alias of Dataset[Row]). From there you can then call `.select("ID", "review")` on it to get those two values as another DataFrame.

On the DF you want to write to HDFS (sorry, I haven't written to DynamoDB from spark... yet), you would call `.write.json/csv/parquet(hdfs_path)` where json/csv/parquet/etc represents whatever format you want written to the HDFS directory.